# Automatically trim white space from columns when mapping with Dapper

Tags: c#, ado.net, dapper

I'm using Dapper to hit a legacy database and there's whitespace padding on the column.

The solution I've found is to add properties like:

```
private string _status;
public string status 
{
    get { return _status; }
    set { _status = value.Trim(); }
}
```

Obviously this is tedious to do on every string member of every model that will interact with this database. According to the [MSDN Entry on SET ANSI_PADDING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx), modifying this to OFF isn't an option either.

As the database is not mine, I'm unable to change it to nvarchar or simiar.

Is there an easy way to force Dapper to trim every string column that it reads from the database?

Comment: short answer: no; how many columns are we talking about here?

Comment: Up to a dozen, over quite a number of models, so it's a lot of redundant code to have floating around.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`Dapper.Contrib`](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs). The `Get` method can generate a change tracking proxy over each returned instance if it is an interface type.

(From the comments for the `Get` method)

> Returns a single entity by a single id from table "Ts". T must be of interface type. 
>     Id must be marked with [Key] attribute.
>     Created entity is tracked/intercepted for changes and used by the Update() extension.

You could look to modify the `CreateProperty` method to implement your `Trim` logic

Comment: I'm currently using `con.Query<StatusModel>(....`, and sometimes I need that as a list, so I'm not sure how Get would work for me returning a single item. 

How can I implement the CreateProperty modification?

Comment: Old post now, but Dapper.Contrib would not help you no.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to write an extension method and use reflection to trim all string properties on the class. For example:

```
public static class ObjExt
{
    public static void Trim<T>(this T item)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            if (p.PropertyType != typeof(string) || !p.CanWrite || !p.CanRead) { continue; }
            var value = p.GetValue(item) as string;
            p.SetValue(item,value.Trim());
        }
    }
}
```